# pylsp.plugins.flake8_lint - Error while running flake8 '/home/alper/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages is in the MYPYPATH. Please remove it

Tags: python, flycheck

In the `*pylsp::stderr*` buffer I keep seeing followin message:

```python
2022-03-08 13:26:17,063 UTC - WARNING - pydocstyle.utils - Error code passed is not a prefix of any known errors: W0603
2022-03-08 13:26:17,063 UTC - WARNING - pydocstyle.utils - Error code passed is not a prefix of any known errors: W1514
2022-03-08 13:26:17,063 UTC - WARNING - pydocstyle.utils - Error code passed is not a prefix of any known errors: R1710
2022-03-08 13:26:17,624 UTC - ERROR - pylsp.plugins.flake8_lint - Error while running flake8 '/home/alper/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages is in the MYPYPATH. Please remove it.
See https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_mypy.html#how-mypy-handles-imports for more info
```

How can I prevent this error?

---

Output of `flycheck-verify-setup`:

```
Syntax checkers for buffer Driver.py in python-mode:

First checker to run:

  lsp (explicitly selected)
    - may enable:    yes
    - may run:       t
    - next checkers: python-flake8, python-mypy

Checkers that may run as part of the first checker's chain:

  python-flake8
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /usr/bin/python3
    - configuration file: Found at "/home/alper/.config/flake8"
    - `flake8' module:    Found at "/home/alper/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flake8/__init__.py"
    - next checkers:      python-mypy, python-pylint

  python-mypy
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /home/alper/venv/bin/mypy
    - configuration file: Found at "/home/alper/ebloc-broker/pyproject.toml"

Checkers that could run if selected:

  python-pycheckers  select
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /home/alper/.emacs.d/elpa/flycheck-pycheckers-20211122.235/bin/pycheckers.py
    - configuration file: Found at "/home/alper/.pylintrc"

  python-pyright  select
    - may enable: yes
    - executable: Found at /home/alper/venv/bin/pyright

Checkers that are compatible with this mode, but will not run until properly configured:

  python-pylint (manually disabled) enable
    - may enable:         yes
    - executable:         Found at /home/alper/venv/bin/pylint
    - configuration file: Found at "/home/alper/.pylintrc"
    - next checkers:      python-mypy

  python-pycompile (manually disabled) enable
    - may enable:    yes
    - executable:    Found at /home/alper/venv/bin/python3
    - next checkers: python-mypy

Flycheck Mode is enabled.  Use C-u C-c ! x to enable disabled checkers.
```

output of `elpy-config`:

```
Elpy Configuration

Emacs.............: 29.0.50
Elpy..............: 1.35.0
Virtualenv........: venv (/home/alper/venv/)
Interactive Python: ~/venv/bin/python3 3.8.10 (/home/alper/venv/bin/python3)
RPC virtualenv....: rpc-venv (/home/alper/.cache/emacs/elpy/rpc-venv)
 Python...........: python 3.8.10 (/home/alper/.cache/emacs/elpy/rpc-venv/bin/python)
 Jedi.............: 0.18.1
 Autopep8.........: 1.6.0
 Yapf.............: 0.32.0
 Black............: 22.1.0
Syntax checker....: flake8 (/home/alper/venv/bin/flake8)
```

My config related to `flake8`:

```
(add-to-list 'flycheck-disabled-checkers 'python-flake8)
(setq flycheck-checker 'flake8)
(setq flycheck-flake8rc "~/.flake8rc")
(setq flycheck-python-flake8-executable "/usr/bin/python3")  ;; skip venv
(setq flycheck-python-pylint-executable "/usr/bin/python3")  ;; skip venv
(setq flycheck-python-complie-executable "/usr/bin/python3") ;; skip venv
(setq flycheck-disabled-checkers '(python-pylint)) ;; running out side venv
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'python-docstring-mode)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook 'lsp)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'lsp-deferred)
(setq-default lsp-pyls-configuration-sources ["flake8"])
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (λ ()
            (setq flycheck-python-pylint-executable "~/venv/bin/pylint")
            (setq flycheck-pylintrc "~/.pylintrc")
            (setq indent-tabs-mode  nil
                  python-indent-offset  4
                  tab-width         4)
            (let ((inhibit-message  t))
              (my-set-fill-column 80)
              )))

(use-package python :ensure nil)
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook #'flycheck-python-setup)

(use-package flycheck-pycheckers
  :after flycheck
  :ensure t
  :init
  (with-eval-after-load 'flycheck
    (add-hook 'flycheck-mode-hook #'flycheck-pycheckers-setup)
    )
  (setq flycheck-pycheckers-checkers
    '(
      mypy3
      )
    )
  )

(add-to-list 'flycheck-checkers 'solidity-checker)
(add-to-list 'flycheck-checkers 'solium-checker)
(setq flycheck-solidity-solc-addstd-contracts t)
(setq solidity-flycheck-solc-checker-active t)
(setq solidity-flycheck-solium-checker-active t)
(flycheck-add-next-checker 'python-flake8 'python-pylint 'python-mypy)
(setq python-python-command "~/venv/bin/python3"
      python-shell-interpreter "~/venv/bin/python3"
      python-shell-interpreter-args "-i"
      python-shell-prompt-detect-failure-warning nil
      flycheck-python-pycompile-executable "python3"
      python-shell-completion-native-enable nil
      python-shell-completion-native-disabled-interpreters '("python3")
      )

(add-hook 'lsp-managed-mode-hook
          (λ ()
            (when (derived-mode-p 'python-mode)
              (add-to-list 'flycheck-disabled-checkers 'python-pylint)
              (add-to-list 'flycheck-disabled-checkers 'python-pycompile)
              (setq my/flycheck-local-cache
                    '((lsp . ((next-checkers . (python-flake8 python-mypy)))))))))
```

Comment: Do not use both ```elpy``` and ```lsp``` - use only lsp, since elpy is validated only for python up to version 3.4. Also be sure you have the right ```pylsp``` server installed  - I searched with google for pylsp.plugins.flake8_lint and found only one reference containing ```flake8_lint```, belonging to ```pyls```, not ```pylsp```. Also, seems to me you over-configure ```flycheck```, some checkers may be enabled/configured from ```lsp``` (e.g. ```mypy```). See this: https://emacs-lsp.github.io/lsp-mode/page/lsp-pylsp/.

Comment: How could I disable my usage for `elpy` ? I installed elpy just to show `elpy-config` section usually I don't use it

Comment: Comment out or delete all references to ```elpy```, starting with ```(require 'elpy)```. Also try to install python in your home folder, instead of ```~/.emacs.d/caches/....```. If you previously used ```pyls``` and the ```venv``` remains the same, delete it and create a new one, since the cache folder inside may contain references to ```pyls```.